# error when change master page with code in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

i have 2 master page 
"Main.Master" and "MainAr.Master"
and i have page "Default.aspx" inherit from baseclass

```
public class BaseClass:Page
{
    protected override void InitializeCulture()
    {
        if (Session["Lang"] != null)
        {
            if (Session["lang"].ToString() == "ar")
            {
                this.UICulture ="ar";
                this.Culture = "ar-EG";

                this.Theme = "ar";
            }
            else if(Session["Lang"].ToString()=="en")
            {

                this.UICulture = "en";
                this.Culture = "en";
                this.Theme = "en";
            }

        }
        else
        {
            this.UICulture = "en";
            this.Culture = "en";
           // this.Theme = "en";
        }


    }
    protected override void OnPreInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["Lang"] != null)
        {
            if (Session["lang"].ToString() == "ar")
            {
                this.Page.Master.MasterPageFile = "~/MainAr.Master";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

in onPreinit void master page of default page must be changed in runtime this is the code of inhertnce

```
 public partial class Default : Utilities.BaseClass
```

but in change master page code i got this error

```
Content controls have to be top-level controls
in a content page or a nested master page that references a master page.
```

2 master page code is

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
 CodeBehind="Main.master.cs"  Inherits="MotahedaWeb.Main" %>

 <!DOCTYPE html>

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head runat="server">
 <title></title>
 <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
 </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
 <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</form>
</body>
```

and the default.aspx page code is

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Main.Master"
 AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="MotahedaWeb.Default" %>
 <%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/Main.Master" %>
 <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
 </asp:Content>

 <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
 </asp:Content>
```

any ideas? ,thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be correct. You only need to make sure that the ContentPlaceholderIds are consistent across the pages you are swapping between (that's what causing that error message)

Comment: of course the contentplaceholders are consistent across the pages